# Installing Go on Linux, testing fails

Tags: linux, go

I'm following the instructions at [this page](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.6.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz) to try to install Go.  I have downloaded the file and extracted it without issue.  I opened the `profile` file and went to the end of the file where I inserted the indicated `export` line.  I created all the indicated directories to make a tree structure, ran the `export` command from the bash shell, created the `hello.go` file as instructed.

Yet when I run `go install github.com/user/hello` I get the error

```
can't load package: package github.com/user/hello: cannot find package "github.com/user/hello" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/user/hello (from $GOROOT)
/work/src/github.com/user/hello (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: Can you try `pwd` in the directory where you attempted to run `go install github.com/user/hello` and let us know what it says?

Comment: @edwinksl It says `/home/muname/work/github.com/user/hello`, thanks.

Comment: Then you should run `go install ./hello` instead.

Comment: @edwinksl I get the same error still.  I think dmitryo's answer below is onto something because he had me run `which go` and the result was `/usr/local/go/bin/go` which is clearly weird and somehow wrong.  Still, the fix for this isn't working.

Comment: Why is that weird? It makes sense to me since the `go` binary is inside the `/usr/local/go/bin` directory.

Comment: Oh, I assumed it was some kind of error because I wouldn't expect multiple files in a hierarchy to be named `go`.  Then I guess it's as it should be, and one of the answers resolved the problem.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/work
cd $GOPATH
mkdir src
mv github.com src/
```

Go expects your source code to be in a directory called `src`.

Comment: Son of a bitch it worked.  So I guess this means I passed the test, and if any other packages depend on Go then I should be fine?

Answer (score 4):

Your GOPATH needs to be your project location, so if you have structure like

```
/var/www/mydir/go
```

so you have to export

```
export GOPATH=/var/www/mydir/go
```

to set GOROOT use your go location

```
which go
```

and if it gives you /usr/local/go/bin/go , you need o set it to /usr/local/go

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

Also, add your go to the PATH (if not there yet):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

For future reuse add all 3 export statements to your ~/.bashrc and/or ~/.bahsrc_profile

At this point you should be able to use 'go get'

Comment: You're definitely onto something because when I type 'which go' I get exactly what you predict.  However, I typed the `export` command that you give, and it doesn't change what `which go` gives.  I followed all the rest of your instructions, too, and still I get the same error message--presumably because something is going wrong or unusual with the `export` stuff.

Comment: In your go dir get rid of your older src and pkg and do a fresh setup of your go modules. Use "go get" to get something installed

Comment: Can you point me to some instructions about how to do a fresh setup of the modules?  I'm pretty new to Linux and never heard about Go before today, so don't really know what all this is.

Comment: Read https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html and https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.6.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz page