# Windows GoClipse Error

Tags: go, goclipse

I tried to configure GoClipse for windows but I get this error when I made a Hello World program: "Executable file (C:\Projects\Go\bin\HelloWorld.exe) doesnt exist." I have GOROOT set to C:\Go and GOPATH set to C:\Projects\Go; I have also installed gocode and created the src, pkg, and bin folders within C:\Projects\Go. I created the go project inside of C:\Projects\Go\src as well. Is there anything that I did wrong or need to fix? I'm not too sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: If you navigate to `C:\Projects\Go\bin` do you see a file named `HellowWorld.exe` ? The error is saying it's not there. Which is probably correct because I bet it's instead at `C:\Projects\Go\src\bin`

Comment: Your GOROOT has to be the directory where your bin/go.exe seats - follow the tutorial on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113298/installing-go-on-linux-testing-fails/38113375#38113375 with Windows adjustments and set PATH accordingly.